# How to make separate rows with Materialize CSS cards in div columns?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to make a vertically scrollable div that has three columns which contain one card (from Materialize CSS, see link here: http://materializecss.com/cards.html
in each row. There should be multilple rows, around ten or twelve for now, so ten or twelve cards per column. But when I tried to do this with just two or three cards in the first and second column, the cards just overlay on top of each other and don't actually make their own rows.

```css
#heading{
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

.card {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
    <div class = "featureditems" style = "overflow-y: scroll">
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
            <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div height = "100px" class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: i have answered your question can you mark it as resolved, for the community

Comment: @M0ns1f, your code does not work properly when browser width < 720px. Then the overlap still exsists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#heading{
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

.card {
 /*add inline-display*/
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
            <div class = "featureditems" style = "overflow-y: scroll">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
                      <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div height = "100px" class="card row">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
                       <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                                             <div height = "100px" class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
                       <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                          <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                          <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

how about now

Comment: This works, thanks! Sorry it took so long to mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the following structure in your body:

- `.featureditems` is a column of N `.card-row` rows (3 in your case)
- three `.card-row` containers in `.featureditems`: one with 3, one with 2 and 1  with 1 materialize `.card` cards.

Modifications:

- Remove **all** inline styling
- Add the code from the snippet

The overlap will be gone, responsiveness for free and commented code, so you should be good to go.

```css
.featureditems,
.card-row       { display: flex }           /* make them flexbox containers */
.featureditems  { flex-flow: column wrap }  /* a column of 1 to N rows (3 in your case) */

.card-row       { flex-flow: row wrap;      /* wrap to next row of cards when current row is full */
                  justify-content: center } /* modify justification as required (probably 'flex-start') */

.card           { flex: 0 1 20rem; margin: .5rem } /* don't grow, but do create a mobile break point at 320px width */
                                                   /* change to 'flex: 1 1 20rem' to see alternattive effect */

main            { padding: .5rem } /* with equal sized card margins you will get a nice 1rem space around each card */
                                   /* 'main' not really required for '.featureditems' to work */

/* ::before,::after,*  { outline: 1px dashed } /* show element outlines for debug, remove when done */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
    <div class = "featureditems">
        <div class="card-row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7f/8d/2c/7f8d2cc47b1851081ec19b3da1d35699.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/554083560386026921/">Visit the site</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```